# Compile project dependency with build tool version - react native

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build.gradle, build-tools

In react-native project app/build.gradle is defined as follows. The root project uses a build tool version of 26.0.2 while the dependencies has various versions.

```
dependencies {
   ...
   compile project(':react-native-config')
   ...
}
```

Is there a way that I could define the `buildToolVersion` while defining the dependencies where all gradle files of the project would normalized with a same `buildToolVersion`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehow I figured out a way. By adding following snippet to the root build.gradle it can be easily done.

```
subprojects {
    ...
    afterEvaluate { subproject ->
        if ((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || 
            subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
            android {
                buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
            }
        }
    }

}
```

During build, it change each of android dependency version into the required.